# Increasing JVM max heap size in MAC OSX 10.12

Tags: java, jvm

I am running MATLAB in my MAC OSX 10.12 (16 GB of memory). I want to increase the JVM 1.8 max heap for using MATLAB without issues. The current size I have is:

```
 uintx MaxHeapSize    := 4294967296    {product}
```

To increase, I used the following command to set 8GB max memory:

```
$java -Xms1g -Xmx8g MATLAB_R2016b.app
```

but I get this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MATLAB_R2016b.app
```

I don't know how to solve that. I googled it but still not finding the solution. Thank you

Comment: how were you launching it before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try system preferences-> java control panel-> java -> click on view... then modify the Runtime args for the user

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What to put in runtime args? I tried `-Xmx8g` but does not work

Comment: I am assuming that you are using 64bit. How did you launch the app before? Does it a system preferences icon?

Comment: Yes, it is 64bit and I launched it from system preferences icon

Comment: Then check in the system preferences for matlab if there is a way to change the java args.

Comment: or try the following: cd into matlab app then try to launch from there. You would need to get the command that is used. Check plist

Comment: My java control panel does not have a java tab

Comment: @J.Doe I believe you are using Java 10 or so (my java 10 installation does not have it either) In a pinch https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624 might help. Export idk options section

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -Xms1g -Xmx8g options in MATLAB specific file "java.opts" and recreate the app and run